# Reading data from 4 static CSV files in Android : Best Approach?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, csv

I have 4 static CSV files containing data. Each file is around 1.1 to 1.5 M each . I want to read the data from these files and let the user select which file and what information he needs from that file.
Keeping in mind a performance access on Android devices, i am trying to get a better approach to read this data. 
I know that using a CSV reader is faster but i am confused if i should use SQLite db instead.  Also I am not sure if it is a right approach to store  4 SQLite db on the phone and read from it.
And ideas about the approach i should take to get the data from these 4 CSV files in a faster way using less memory and more processing speed. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both.

On first use of the app read the CSV files and import them to a SQLite database.

From then on query the database.